# How to use NSTimers as associative references?

Tags: objective-c

I've tried the following:

```
- (void)setupTimer {    
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, timer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    [timer invalidate];
}

- (void)doSomething { /* ... */ }
- (void)afterDoingSomething { [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key) invalidate]; }
```

Yet, the timer doesn't tick (I didn't expected it to do so; this code just didn't look much right to me) for some reason. Is there a way to  make it... work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're invalidating the timer immediately after creating and scheduling it. Remove the `[timer invalidate];` line in `-setupTimer`:

```
- (void)setupTimer {    
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, timer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate):

> [invalidate] stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests
>   its removal from its run loop.

Am I correct in assuming that this code is in a category? Otherwise, I can't think of a good reason to make the timer an associated object instead of just using a regular instance variable for it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Although, if I'm retaining the timer inside my associative reference, wouldn't I be leaking if I didn't dispose of the timer?

Comment: `-invalidate` has nothing to do with memory management. It's for canceling the timer so it won't fire. It's not the same thing as `release`. Second, the `-scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` method returns an autoreleased instance, so you're not responsible for releasing it. You should get rid of the associative reference in `-afterDoingSomething` when you're done with the timer. You can do that by calling `objc_setAssociatedObject()` again with nil. You needn't to call release on the timer, as the associative reference function(s) will do that. Might be good to review ObjC memory managment...

Answer (score 1):

You've must have mistaken `invalidate` and `release`.
`objc_setAssociatedObject` does `release` for you when you set next item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem with setting a timer as an associative reference.

1. You are killing your timer before it actually start (`invalidate` does so).
2. Your `- (void)doSomething` method should have different signature: `- (void)doSomething: (NSTimer*)theTimer`.
3. You may be leaking memory, you should do `objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);` in your `afterDoingSomething`.